# Type aliasing ordered generics in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, comparable, type-alias

I have a minimal definition of what a binary tree should look like:

```
type Tree[T] = Option[Node[T]]
case class Node[T](left: Tree[T], entry: T, right: Tree[T])
```

I now want to define a binary **search** tree as:

```
type BST[T: Ordering] = Tree[T]
```

but that does not compile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compile error you're getting basically says that *context bounds* cannot be used for type aliases. Context bounds do work in function or class definitions. For example,

```
class BST[T: Ordering](val tree: Tree[T])
```

is actually shorthand notation for

```
class BST[T](val tree: Tree[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T])
```

Note that different `BST` objects could potentially have different `Ordering`s, and those values must be stored at runtime.

For your use case, the easiest thing might be to put the context bound on the generic functions you have in mind,

```
def f[T: Ordering](t1: Tree[T], t2: Tree[T]) {
  import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
  t1.get.entry < t2.get.entry
}
```

Then the appropriate `Ordering[T]` implicit will be found at the call site of `f`, where the type `T` is known.

Comment: You mean "Shorthand notation for: `class BST[T](val tree: Tree[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T])`"